# Come back on my library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle

I tried to use an application with nokogiri, but after a lot of problems, I decided to uninstall it. And now I have an error when I run my server. I think it's because I switched to another library with this command:

```
bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include/libxml2
```

So how can I switch back to my original repository?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We don't answer questions by putting the solution in the question, instead, create an answer, and SO will give you the ability to select it after an appropriate timeout period. Selecting an answer tells us, and the system, that your question has a suitable solution. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: That's actually what the op did - another user edited it into their question